# How to add python module in codeiginiter web application?

Tags: php, python, json, google-analytics, service-accounts

I'm working to develop new feature in my web app that gets Google Analytics charts using service account and one of process that written in decontamination is

> Step 3: Use the JSON key data to request an access token and I install library Google API Client Library for Python.

Now I want to know how can I put a JSON key in python module and import the python script I'm my app to invoke `get_access_token()` method in JS script,

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization#service_accounts) : First you have to register a service account.

> Service accounts are useful for automated, offline, or scheduled
>   access to Google Analytics data for your own account. For example, to
>   build a live dashboard of your own Google Analytics data and share it
>   with other users.

To set up a new service account, do the following:

1. Click **Create credentials > Service account key.**
2. Choose whether to download the service account's public/private key as a standard P12 file, or as a JSON file that can be loaded by a Google API client library.

> Your new public/private key pair is generated and downloaded to your
>   machine; it serves as the only copy of this key. You are responsible
>   for storing it securely.

Then you can download the [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py#3_setup_the_sample).

You'll need to create a single file named HelloAnalytics.py, which will contain the given sample code.

1. Copy or download the following source code to HelloAnalytics.py.
2. Move the previously downloaded client_secrets.json to the same
   directory as the sample code.
3. Replace the value of VIEW_ID. You can
   use the Account Explorer to find a View ID.

i

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secrets.json' # Path to client_secrets.json file.
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes the analyticsreporting service object.

  Returns:
    analytics an authorized analyticsreporting service object.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage('analyticsreporting.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)

  return analytics

def get_report(analytics):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response"""

  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print header + ': ' + dimension

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print 'Date range (' + str(i) + ')'
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value


def main():

  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i wondering after run this script ? whats next or how the data will handle known i`m using codeigniter  web framework?

Comment: And I`m also try to run script and i get this errors ./analytics.py: line 9: SCOPES: command not found
./analytics.py: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./analytics.py: line 10: `DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')'

Comment: To be clear with you I`m now follow [https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/] and also i got the same error when i`m try to run python script @user340764

Comment: @mousa.Alshaikh Seems like you have 2 quotes? ... /rest')'; You only need one, that seems like a syntax error.

Comment: I don`t understand what`s quotes?